# IDataErrorInfo validation isn't giving any 'ErrorContent' (see edit)

Tags: c#, validation, xaml, idataerrorinfo

**What I want to achieve:**

I'm attempting to implement fairly simple Data Validation within TextBoxes. If validation rules are not met, TextBox border turns red and error message is displayed in its ToolTip.

I'm doing this using IDataErrorInfo and Styles/Bindings:

**IDataErrorInfo implementation:**

```
#region DataError Members
public string Error
    { 
        get { return null; } 
    }

    public string this[string propertyName]
    {
        get
        {
            string result = null;

            if (propertyName == "Answer")
            {
                if (Answer != null)
                {
                   if (this.Answer.Length < 1 || this.Answer.Length > 10)
                       result = "Invalid answer length - Must be between: 1 and 10 chars.";                        
                }
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
#endregion
```

**TextBox which contains the binding:**

```
<TextBox       
     Style="{DynamicResource GeneralTextBoxStyle}"
     >
     <TextBox.Text>
         <Binding  
             Path="Answer" 
             Mode="TwoWay" 
             UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"
             ValidatesOnDataErrors="True"
             ValidatesOnExceptions="True"                        
          />
     </TextBox.Text> 
</TextBox>
```

**TextBox Template/Style:**

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="ErrorTextBoxTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
    <Border 
        x:Name="ErrorBorder" 
        BorderThickness="1"
        BorderBrush="White"
        >
        <ScrollViewer 
            x:Name="PART_ContentHost"
            VerticalAlignment="Center"
            >
            <ScrollViewer.ToolTip>
                <ToolTip FontSize="14">
                    <TextBlock x:Name="ToolTip"/>
                </ToolTip>
            </ScrollViewer.ToolTip>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Border>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="true">
            <Setter TargetName="ToolTip" Property="Text" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self}, Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}"/>
            <Setter TargetName="ErrorBorder" Property="BorderBrush" Value="Blue"/>
        </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>

<Style x:Key="ErrorTextBoxStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
    <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource ErrorTextBoxTemplate}"/>
</Style>
```

*Note: XAML code has been stripped down considerably (code concerning layout **only**).*

---

**The Problem:**

The issue which I'm facing is that the binding on the ToolTip TextBlock never seems to show any errors.

Other than that, everything else works perfectly (DataValidation is as expected and the border of my TextBox turns blue).

I'm almost certain that I'm missing something and I can't seem to workout what - It's probably something extremely simple!

Thanks in advance for your responses.

---

**EDIT:**

This is a problem with the way I've setup the ToolTip in the template. Still unsure as to why it doesn't work however the problem is much simpler than what I first thought! So now I guess the question is why does the binding not work within the TextBlock?

I need to do it this way as if I assign directly to 'TextBox.ToolTip', I can no longer access the ToolTip in code (which is a requirement) as it gets converted into a string.

Answer (score 0):

Change the setter for "ToolTip" to:

```
<Setter TargetName="ToolTip" Property="Text" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.TemplatedParent}, Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}"/>
```

When you use `Self` you bind to the `TextBlock` in your tooltip.

If this doesn't work, try `RelativeSource.FindAncestor` with ancestor type set to `TextBox`.

Comment: No luck with either - Tried what you wrote and

`RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type TextBox}}`.